# Analytically determine if dashes in coincident dashed line will overlap

Tags: algorithm

I have a time scheduling problem that can be modeled as dashed lines. Each line is defined by (i) initial gap (d) dash length (g) successive gap, were (d) and (g) repeat indefinitely. For two lines, I want to determine if the dashes will ever overlap in any part.

If I'm willing to set an arbitrary limit (L), I can do this with a brute force classic nested dual loop approach, e.g.

```
for b0 in range(i0, L, d0 + g0):
    e0 = b0 + d0
    for b1 in range(i1, L, d1 + g1):
        e1 = b1 + d1
        if (b1 < e0 < e1) or (b1 < b0 < e1) or (b0 < b1 < e0) or (b0 < e1 < e0):
            return True
return False
```

I think there's simplifications, optimizations, and maybe even an edge case where they exactly match.

But I feel like there should be a mathematical way to determine this analytically, rather than having to loop imperatively. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `c = gcd(d0 + g0, d1 + g1)`. The dashed lines overlap if and only if there exists an integer `k` such that `(i0 + k*c, i0 + d0 + k*c)` overlaps `(i1, i1 + d1)`, by judicious application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The overlap condition is equivalent to `(i0 + k*c < i1 + d1) AND (i1 < i0 + d0 + k*c)`. Solving for `k*c`, we get the equivalent condition `i1 - (i0 + d0) < k*c < (i1 + d1) - i0`. To test whether there exists such an integer `k`, we find the least multiple of `c` greater than the lower bound and check it against the upper bound. The final version of the test is

```
import fractions

def leastMultipleOfGreaterThan(c, l):
    return l + (c - l % c)

leastMultipleOfGreaterThan(fractions.gcd(d0 + g0, d1 + g1), i1 - (i0 + d0)) < (i1 + d1) - i0
```

Note to people porting this code from Python: Python's modulo operator works differently from other languages. You'll need to add some logic to handle the case where `l` is negative (and in languages without bignums, depending on how much you care about this code working for all integer inputs, some code to handle extreme values).